# Symfony 2 twig checkboxes in one line row table with entities

Tags: html, symfony, twig

I would like to get table where inputs checkboxes are in one line row with entity but first row of entity.name< /td> is down one line.
How can I fix this ?

> {% form_theme form _self %}
>
> {% block choice_widget_expanded -%}
>
> ```
>   {%- for child in form %}
> <tr><td> {{- form_label(child) -}} </td>
> <td> {{- form_widget(child)-}} </td>
>  {% endfor -%}
> ```
>
> {% endblock choice_widget_expanded %}
>
> ```
>  {% for entity in entities  %}
>                 {{  form_widget(form.name)}}                    
>                                                            
>           <td>entity.name</td>
>                                                                            
>          </tr> 
>
>        {% endfor %}
> ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It gives me:

```
 <tr>

 <td><label for="...">....</label></td>
 <td><input type="checkbox" id="..." name="...." value="..." /></td>

 <td><label for="">...</label></td>
 <td><input type="checkbox" id="..." name="..." value="..." /></td>

 <td>entity.name</td>

 </tr> 

  <tr>                                      

  <td>entity.name</td>                                     
  </tr>
```

I have to get:

```
<table>
 <tr>
 <td><label for="...">....</label></td>
 <td><input type="checkbox" id="..." name="...." value="..." />...</td>
 <td>entity.name</td>
 </tr> 

 <tr>  
 <td><label for="">...</label></td>
 <td><input type="checkbox" id="..." name="..." value="..." />...</td>                                      
 <td>entity.name</td>                                     
 </tr>    
</table>
```

I solved the problem. I've just set label and input manualy:

```
{% form_theme form _self %}  

    {% block choice_widget_expanded -%}  

  // here empty choice_widget 

  {% endblock choice_widget_expanded %}



 {% for entity in entities  %}

<tr>
    <td>   <label for="form_names_{{entity.name.id}}">{{entity.name}}</label></td>
    <td>   <input id="form_names_{{entity.name.id}}" name="form[names][]" value="{{entity.name.id}}" type="checkbox"></td>

    {{  form_widget(form.names)}}                    

    <td>entity.name</td>

    </tr> 

   {% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

try changing

```
  {%- for child in form %}
**<tr>**<td> {{- form_label(child) -}} </td>
<td> {{- form_widget(child)-}} </td>
 {% endfor -%}
```

into

```
  {%- for child in form %}
<td> {{- form_label(child) -}} </td>
<td> {{- form_widget(child)-}} </td>
 {% endfor -%}
```

and then

```
      **<tr>**
            {{  form_widget(form.name)}}                    

      <td>entity.name</td>

      </tr>
```